# Allocate a share of the total based on the weight of each category

Tags: r

I have the feeling this should be fairly straightforward, but I can't find the solution by myself, nor couldn't I find a post on Stackoverflow that was providing me with a workable answer.

I have a fairly large database, and basically I want to allocate a total from a category that I have from another df to all the rows from the sub-category that belong to the same category, kind of like a rule of 3 (or exactly like a rule of 3).

If I were to do a simple sample, it would be like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(region = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a"),
                  Country = c("ax","ax","ax","ay","ay","az","az"),
                  Employee = c("axa","axc","axc","aya","ayb","aza","azc"),
                  V1 = c(10,10,10,15,12,18,19),
                  V2 = c(20,20,15,13,17,20,18),
                  V3 = c(8,9,10,12,15,30,10))

df2 <- data.frame (territory= c("a","b","c","d"),
                   total = c(2000,1000,5000,3000))
```

I tried this code, but the allocation isn't correct:

```
df_calc <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(
    df2, 
    by = c("region" = "territory")
  ) %>% 
  group_by(region, Country, Employee) %>% 
  mutate(
    across(V1:V3, list(allocation = ~ total * . / sum(.)))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

and ideally, the output would be like:
[image]

Comment: Hi Denis! Can you explain just one value from the expected output. For example, the 212.8 in the first row of V1.allocation. I understand it is multiplied by 10, but how does one get from 2000 (the territory total) to the 212.8?

Comment: Hi Mark ! Thanks for answering ! In the expected output, the 212.8 is obtained by multiplying by 10 and dividing by the sum of the column (94), just so that we can allocate the total of the region (2000) by all the rows within the same region.

Comment: Hi Mark ! Apologies I just realised there were inconsistencies between the df I shared and the image I posted. I corrected the code in the df sample !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2, key = "territory")
stopifnot(anyDuplicated(df2$territory) == 0L)
```

---

```
cols <- c("V1", "V2", "V3")
df1[, 
    (paste0(cols, ".allocation")) :=
      lapply(.SD, \(x) x / sum(x) * df2[region, total]), 
    by      = region, 
    .SDcols = cols]

df1
#    region Country Employee    V1    V2    V3 V1.allocation V2.allocation V3.allocation
#    <char>  <char>   <char> <num> <num> <num>         <num>         <num>         <num>
# 1:      a      ax      axa    10    20     8      212.7660      325.2033      170.2128
# 2:      a      ax      axc    10    20     9      212.7660      325.2033      191.4894
# 3:      a      ax      axc    10    15    10      212.7660      243.9024      212.7660
# 4:      a      ay      aya    15    13    12      319.1489      211.3821      255.3191
# 5:      a      ay      ayb    12    17    15      255.3191      276.4228      319.1489
# 6:      a      az      aza    18    20    30      382.9787      325.2033      638.2979
# 7:      a      az      azc    19    18    10      404.2553      292.6829      212.7660
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sindri !

I actually never used data.table, and I didn't know we could do it that way. 

This was exactly what I needed !!!

Answer (score 0):

based on your comments to Mark, it seems you have applied the wrong group, as you state the that sum for V1 should be 94, based on common region.
therefore :

```
df_calc <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(
    df2, 
    by = c("region" = "territory")
  ) %>% 
  group_by(region) %>% 
  mutate(
    across(V1:V3, list(allocation = ~ total * . / sum(.)))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

I orinally thad thought you have meant to apportion the total across the V1:V3 relative spread per observation, but seems not; so I have removed my old answer

Comment: Hi Nir ! Thanks a ton for sharing ! 

In your code, would there be any way for me to do a sum across the column V1 first (ie all the sums from the vector V1, then V2, then V3)? 

I tried to modify your code by using RowSum(across (everything)) but without success.

Comment: I dont understand your question. "sum across a column" ? there is possibly summing down a column... but how would that relate to your scenario ? or are you asking an unrelated question ? (about a summarise rather than a mutate ?)

Comment: Yes I guess I meant Summing down the column. 

In the scenario, while your solution works across all 3 columns (ie x * total / sum (c_across (V1:V3)), what I needed was actually x * total / Sum (V1) if that makes sense? Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Hi Nir !

Thanks a lot for your help on this one. I will definitely keep in mind the few lines of codes you initially shared. So helpful !